# How do I read the rows in a sheet into an array of custom classes in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel data as below:

```
id  name    Math  Science   English   History
1   James   51    40        94        14
2   John    12    43        15        62
3   Bob     11    88        57        61
4   Peter   25    50        11        45
```

I would like to read that into an array of *Class Student* which will have all the 6 properties.

How do I do in this in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)?

Comment: Please add relevant information on what you've tried and failed to do in the process. Btw, you can find answers by @RonRosenfeld which have a lot of example using classes. You might learn something there or better, solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say your "Sheet1" spreadsheet looks kind of like this:

[image]

When you open Visual Basic Editor <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> you need to right click your VBA project and insert 2 modules: one standard Module1 and one Class Module.

Rename the class module to `Student` and populate it with

```
Public Id As Long
Public Name As String
Public Math As Long
Public Science As Long
Public English As Long
Public History As Long

Public Function GetAverage()
    GetAverage = (Math + Science + English + History) / 4
End Function
```

And the in the `Module1`

```
Sub Main()

    Dim students As New Collection ' collection to store all students


    Dim cell As Range ' iterator
    Dim person As Student

    ' for each cell in column A
    For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        ' create a new student object
        Set person = New Student
        ' fill the data
        person.Id = cell
        person.Name = cell.Offset(0, 1)
        person.Math = cell.Offset(0, 2)
        person.Science = cell.Offset(0, 3)
        person.English = cell.Offset(0, 4)
        person.History = cell.Offset(0, 5)

        ' add the student to the collection of students
        students.Add person
    Next

    ' open Immediate Window CTRL + G or VIEW -> Immediate Window
    Dim s As Student
    For Each s In students
        Debug.Print "ID: " & s.Id & vbTab & "Name: " & s.Name, "Math: " & s.Math, "Science: " & s.Science, "English: " & s.English, "History: " & s.History, "Avg: " & s.getAverage()
    Next

End Sub
```

Now if you run <kbd>F5</kbd> your macro and check out your Immediate Window you will have all the data from your spreadsheet loaded programmatically in to a collection;

[image]

*Note: [I have reblogged this with some additional details](http://vba4all.com/building-a-basic-class-in-vba-based-on-data-in-a-spreadsheet/)

Comment: My only quibble is that the Range is not fully qualified with a Worksheet, other than that it's as good an answer as you'll get for this question.

Comment: @citizenkong I only qualify Range when I am working with more than 1 spreadsheet. In this example I only mention one spreadsheet therefore I didn't think qualifying Range mattered a lot but yeah I guess your point is valid for people with more than 1 spreadsheet.

Comment: I always try to make a point of qualifying Ranges and Sheets - never underestimate the creativity of users!

Comment: @citizenkong so true!

Comment: +1 Good answer! Small side comment: Seems your blog does not like `<kbd>`...

Comment: @PeterAlbert oh yeah. i actually hate wordpress but hey at least it's free ;P

Comment: Install a markdown plugin (I use WP-Markdown) - and you can use SO syntax! Makes life a lot easier! :-)

Comment: +1 and I second citizenkong: as much as your blog helps users (including myself) become more competent, making the code robust and with good naming conventions will also help those who dive into more sophisticated applications. Good job!

Comment: +1 good solution well described!